# What does it mean by "A continuous family of symplectic forms"

Tags: continuity, differential-topology, symplectic-geometry

I have difficulty in understanding the meaning of "**A continuous family of symplectic forms**". I have seen this in many papers on symplectic geometry.

Does it mean, we have a one parameter family $\omega_t$, $t\in [a,b]$ of symplectic forms? If in that case why the word **continuity** though?
  Or does it mean we have a continuous map $f:[a,b]\to \Omega^2_\text{Symp}$, where $\Omega^2_\text{Symp}$ is the space of all symplectic forms on an ambient manifold? But in this case what is the topology of $\Omega^2_\text{Symp}$?

Can anyone please help clarify the definition for **continuous family**. Thanks in advance

Comment: The set of symplectic forms is a subset of the bundle of 2-forms, so it has the subspace topology.

Comment: @Pedro Brunialti I don't get what you are saying.. . The space of symplectic forms is a subspace of the 2-form right? Not a subspace of the bundle

Comment: What's the setting of this question? Are you considering a continuous family of symplectic forms on a family of symplectic manifold?

Comment: You can think of a family as a map $$M \times [a,b]\rightarrow \Omega^2(M)$$ where for each fixed $t\in [a,b]$ we have a form. Thus, this family is symplectic if it takes values in symplectic forms.

Comment: Yes, this is indeed unclear since there is no "canonical" topology on $\Omega^2(M)$. A common choice is to use the topology of $C^\infty$-convergence.

Comment: You can also avoid the subtleties of topologizing $\Omega^2M$ by regarding the family as a continuous map $\omega:\mathbb{R}\times M\to \Lambda^2T^*M$ such that  each partial evaluation $\omega_t:M\to\Lambda^2T^*M$ is a symplectic form.